# Unable to change password of a VM through Azure Automation

Tags: powershell

I have a created a Powershell script with Function "RandomPassword" to randomly generate a password. But, I am unable to set the user password to randomly generated password. Below is the PS script and error I am encountering -

PSScript -

```
Function RandomPassword {

$ABC="A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"
$abc="a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
$char="!","@","#","$","%","*"
$num="1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"

$Upper=Get-Random -count 1 -InputObject $ABC
$Lower=Get-Random -count 5 -InputObject $abc
$Char=Get-Random -count 1 -InputObject $char
$Num=Get-Random -count 1 -InputObject $num

$All=Get-Random -Count 7 -InputObject ($Lower+$Char+$Num)
$Raw=$All -join("")

$Temppassword = $Upper + $Raw
$Temppassword
}

$RandomPassword=RandomPassword
$RandomPassword

Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword $RandomPassword -Identity <username>
```

Error -

```
Set-ADAccountPassword : Cannot bind parameter 'NewPassword'. Cannot convert the "qkqjh#8w" value of type "System.String" to 
type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

I have also used this line, but it did not not help and I am receiving same error

```
$SecPaswd=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $RandomPassword -AsPlainText -Force
```

Is there a way I could achieve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, I would say that the suggested solution would help and it would not be possible to get the same error as `$SecPaswd` is indeed of the type System.Security.SecureString.

You should of course also change the Parameter in the line:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword $RandomPassword -Identity <username>
```

where `$RandomPassword` should be changed to `$SecPaswd`.

Comment: Hi Marlies, thanks you for reply. This has been tried already. When I am using "$SecPaswd=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $RandomPassword -AsPlainText -Force", I am changing the script to be "Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword $SecPaswd -Identity <username>". Both the time I am receiving the same error

Comment: Could you update your question script with the script with the thing you tried in it? I would expect a slightly different error than the one mentioned, because the error mentions the password in plain text while I expect that passing $SecPaswd to the function, it would not be possible for the error to mention the string plain text.